# Running .EXE file in SSIS Script Task

Tags: ssis-2012, msbi

I'm running a .EXE file through SSIS script task,

The EXE file is used for generating XML file , after that It ask for ENTER to complete the task. I dont want to press "ENTER" manually, how to solve this .This need to automate.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Console.Quit() or Console.Exit() ?

Comment: I need to handle this in  Execute process task of SSIS... any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a text file that contains a blank line. Call this file return.txt
2. Run you exe as: myprogram.exe < return.txt

This will pipe the blank line as an input to the exe, meaning the exe will accept this as an input instead of waiting.

Comment: I got the logic.. but how to handle through SSIS.

Comment: Create a BAT file and run it from a EXE task in SSIS